# Hide Android System Bar in tablets via Firmware

Tags: android, root, android-firmware

I need to know the process or application that shows the system bar (home button, back button, settings) in android tablets. I need to kill this process or application to avoid the user access to the android settings. I have the possibility to do this in a custom android firmware.

What do I need modify in the android code to hide this bar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at [HideBar](https://github.com/ppareit/HideBar) on GitHub. The process is `com.android.systemui` and HideBar shows the specific Service class names. You can use `ActivityManager` or `Process` to kill it but since it is a system process it is possible that it will cause instability and possibly respawn itself.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching on the internet, I managed to get the System Bar to hide and appear in a 4.2 device using:

To Hide:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui");
```

Or use 79 instead of 42 for API less than 14. You may also need to include the SET_DEBUG_APP permission, in which case you need to have the application signed with the system key or installed in the /system/app/ directory.

To Show:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am startservice --user 0 -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService");
```

If using API 4.0 to 4.1, remove the --user 0 option. Alternatively some people have used the -a (instead of -n) option, though this was causing an error on my device:

Error: Not found; no service started.